# TypeError: fs.existsSync is not a function getElectronPath C:/Users/ahsab/Desktop/app_react//node_modules/electron/index.js:8

Tags: reactjs, electron, cross-platform

when i try to import path then this error occured and when i don't import path then show me another error that path module can't found. how can i solve this issue ?

[Errors here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/boTY4.png) 
[My Code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpLKJ.png)

Comment: Error Screenshot here https://i.stack.imgur.com/boTY4.png

Comment: here is my code screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpLKJ.png

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Don't use images, **paste your code**. For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)